# Finding all functions that satisfy $ f(x) +3f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = x^2 $

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all the functions $f: \mathbb R^*\to \mathbb R $ such that:
> $$ \forall x\in \mathbb R^*: f(x) +3f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = x^2 $$

My answers or what I tried to do is:

I put $f$ as a solution to the basic equation and I followed the substitution method by giving $x=0$ which gives us $f(0)=0$ and it led me nothing since this method has usually two variables.

So, I tried next both of injectivity and surjectivity but it's still a dead end.

Note: This is not a homework (since school is over). I just wanted a more valable or strategic method to this kind of equations since we never studied it I just found in a book but I couldn't understand it very well alone.

Comment: Notice that 0 does not belong in your domain. What is f(1/0)?

Comment: substitute $\frac 1x$ for $x$ in your equations.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $1/x$ for $x$ and we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(1/x)+3f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply this by $3$ and subtract the orignal eqaution & we have ...

Comment: Yes Thnak you I just solved it, I found $$ f(x) = \cfrac{3-x^2}{8x^2} $$

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) = \cfrac{3-\color{red}{x^4}}{8x^2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $\frac{1}{x} \mapsto x$ and then multiplying both sides by $3$, we have that:

$$3 f \left(\frac{1}{x} \right) + 9f(x) = \frac{3}{x^2}$$
$$-3  f \left(\frac{1}{x} \right) - f(x) = -x^2$$

which implies $8f(x) = \frac{3}{x^2} - x^2$, or $f(x) = \frac{3-x^4}{8x^2}$.